# How to clone a git repository via SSH public key authentication without using user name in git clause?

Tags: git, ssh, putty

I am using pass-phrase protected SSH public/private key authentication to access my git repository via SSH in Windows.

First, I try the Putty solution by using plink.exe and pageant.exe.  I have GIT_SSH variable set to  plink.exe.

If I attempt to clone a repository:

```
c:\> git clone ssh://git.example.com/srv/repos/git/project.git project
```

I got error:

```
Cloning into project...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is due to I didn't specify user name for ssh access.

Adding user name will make the clone work:

```
c:\> git clone ssh://user@git.example.com/srv/repos/git/project.git project
```

The reason I don't add user name to git clone is I am using submodule that doesn't specify user name in .gitmodules.

Is there anyway to make git + plink using user name specify somewhere else?

Next, I try the default ssh.exe of msysgit, I may specify user name in %HOME%/.ssh/config.  However, I couldn't get ssh-agent.exe and ssh-add.exe work with passphrased protected private key.

Comment: Corey: I am aware the different key format.  Both OpenSSH and Putty doesn't work well with passphrase protected private key in Windows for git.